# Creating a weather app in Java

Tags: java, api, weather

I want to create a weather app in Java, just for fun.
I know how to use the GeoIP database by MaxMinds to map IP to location.

I was planning on using this to auto-detect a user's location and display the weather information on a clean, simple GUI.

My friend used the API of `BackStage BBC` that was given to him by his Uni but he said he could not hand it to me as he was not allowed to.

What other alternative APIs do I have available to get weather info ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming question **after** your research.

Comment: [here's a link that may help you further.](http://bit.ly/153OxSo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The complete list of [APIs in the Weather category](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Weather) at ProgrammableWeb might be your first stop to decide which API you would like to use.
2. A majority of these APIs support the REST standard and that would be your primary mechanism to integrate the information into your Java application.